# Unable to read CSV file in C++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to read key-value pairs from a csv file, but have been unable to access the data from the file. This is what I have tried so far.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

map<string, string> hash_table;

void load_map(){

    // File pointer
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("output.csv", ios::in);

    // Read the Data from the file
    // as String Vector
    string temp;
    string line;

    while (fin >> temp) {
        getline(fin, line);
        cout << line[0];
        //hash_table.insert(line[0], line[1]);
        }
}

int main()
{
    load_map();
    cout << hash_table.size();
    cout << hash_table["A12B12C11D11E11F11G10"];
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing prints out except for the map size which is 0.

Comment: You're never inserting anything into `hash_table`. You need to parse your line into (I assume) a key and a value and insert them.

Comment: while loop causes the problem .You can try without the while loop.                         
 //while (fin >> temp) {
  getline(fin, line);
  cout << line[0];
  cout << line;
  //hash_table.insert(line[0], line[1]);
 //}

Comment: @Rahul, how would you try this without the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
//hash_table.insert(line[0], line[1]);
```

Is not valid way to insert key-value pair.
Additionally, rather than having while(fin >> temp),
replace it by

```
while(getline(fin, line))
```

then remove

```
getline(fin, line);
```

as its function is replaced by

```
while(getline(fin, line)){...}
```

Then, separate line to key-value (assuming the csv is separated by ',') by insert some code right under the
    //hash_table.insert(line[0], line[1]);
like:

```
string key, value;
stringstream tok(line);
getline(tok, key, ',');
getline(tok, value);
hash_table.insert({key,value});
```

After that, some key-value pairs will be in.

Comment: This worked after adding this header: #include <bits/stdc++.h>

Comment: is this the correct way to access the value in my map:  hash_table["A48B44C40D37E24F14G0"]; ?